Having multiple .dll file links to change a single file instead of all of them
I wanted to use mklink to create multiple file links for Nvidia's DLSS .dll file, so that I can change a single file to update instead of swapping all of them individually.
However, symbolic links don't work with .dll files and hard links remain linked to the original file even after it's deleted, so there's no ability to swap files. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?
I know a workaround of making myself a script that deletes all the files and creates new hard links, but that's not exactly what I am trying to achieve and besides there is a lot of those files.

I guess my first thought is why not have one copy  on the PATH (perhaps in system32) and just delete all the others? I'm sure there is a reason that won't work, but directory-local DLLs are generally used in cases where the dll is only used by one app, or when you seek to override the global version of the library.

I'm not sure how the games handle these DLLs exactly, I believe they have to be in the local directory and each game has their own files with different version, but they can be upgraded manually and improve DLSS

easy to test, rename one games dll, make sure its high on the PATH, and try to run the game. the idea that a version must be specific because the game relies on it being a specific distributed version, doesn't really support the idea that it can be manually upgraded, or that it wouldn't use path lookup if missing. just my two bits

What do you mean by PATH? Putting the .dll in environment variables?

the PATH is an environment variable that contains an ordered series of directories. when you invoke an executable or an executable loads a library that is linked without a specific path, the runtime environment will check each directory from the beginning of the list until it finds a file with a matching name. Once the object is found, it is used, so directories toward the front of the list will be preferred if there is more than one copy of the object. Since c:\windows\system32 generally appears toward the front of the directory list, I'd probably put it there.

I've tried placing the .dll in system32, tried adding a directory containing the .dll to the top of PATH and lastly tried adding .dll path to the top and none of this worked when the .dll file was removed from the game's directory.

Okay I've given up and just asked ChatGPT to write a .bat script that replaces all the files. All the target directories are stored in a .txt file and even I suddenly gained 50 more files that need to included in the replacement I can just search for "nvngx_dlss.dll" with Everything, select all, right click and Copy Full Name to clipboard and then just paste it in the dlss_paths.txt only having to remove some exceptions
